# When the underlying files have changed, should PySpark refresh the view or the source tables?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say we have a Hive table `foo` that's backed by a set of parquet files on e.g. `s3://some/path/to/parquet`. These files are known to be updated at least once per day, but not always at the same hour of the day.

I have a view on that table, for example defined as

```
spark.sql("SELECT bar, count(baz) FROM foo GROUP BY bar").createOrReplaceTempView('foo_view')
```

When I use the `foo_view` the application will occasionally fail with

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 975.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 975.0 (TID 116576, 10.56.247.98, executor 193): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file s3a://some/path/to/parquet. It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running &#39;REFRESH TABLE tableName&#39; command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

I've tried prefixing all my queries on `foo_view` with a call to `spark.catalog.refreshTable('foo')`, but the problem keeps on showing up.

Am I doing this right? Or should I call `refreshTable()` on the *view* instead of the source table?

Comment: after refreshing the table, did you recreate the view?

Comment: @E.ZY. so after refreshing all source tables, I should recreate all views that directly or indirectly depend on them?

Comment: yes ideally, otherwise, the view is defined are still referring to the old